# sed Capital_Case not working

Tags: shell, awk, sed, zsh

I'm trying to convert a string that has either `-` (hyphen) or `_` (underscore) to Capital_Case string.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

function cap_case() {
  [ $# -eq 1 ] || return 1;
  _str=$1;
  _capitalize=${_str//[-_]/_} | sed -E 's/(^|_)([a-zA-Z])/\u\2/g'
  echo "Capitalize:"
  echo $_capitalize
  return 0
}

read string
echo $(cap_case $string)
```

But I don't get anything out.

First I am replacing any occurrence of `-` and `_` with `_` `${_str//[-_]/_}`, and then I pipe that string to `sed` which finds the first letter, or `_` as the first group, and then the letter after the first group in the second group, and I want to uppercase the found letter with `\u\2`. I tried with `\U\2` but that didn't work as well.

I want the string `some_string` to become

```
Some_String
```

And string `some-string` to become

```
Some_String
```

I'm on a mac, using zsh if that is helpful.

Comment: Don't use `sh` as your shebang. Even though `/bin/sh` is really `bash`, it behaves differently when invoked as `sh`. That said, are you really executing your script with `sh` or `bash`, or will it be executed with `zsh`?

Comment: zsh is a possibility, not an imposition?

Comment: I'm using `sh test.sh` when testing this as a shell script

Comment: If you are using `sh` (or even `./test.sh` with the given shebang), it's irrelevant that you are calling the script *from* an instance of `zsh`. (That said, there is nothing stopping you from writing the script in `zsh` as well, in which case my answer can apply.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** More generic solution here to make each field's first letter Capital.

```
echo "some_string_other" | awk -F"_" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)}} 1' OFS="_"
```

---

Following `awk` may help you.

```
echo "some_string" | awk -F"_" '{$1=toupper(substr($1,1,1)) substr($1,2);$2=toupper(substr($2,1,1)) substr($2,2)} 1' OFS="_"
```

Output will be as follows.

```
echo "some_string" | awk -F"_" '{$1=toupper(substr($1,1,1)) substr($1,2);$2=toupper(substr($2,1,1)) substr($2,2)} 1' OFS="_"
Some_String
```

Comment: I got Some_string_ when I used this :/

Comment: @dingo_d, sorry didn't get it, please explain.

Comment: I added your code instead the `_capitalize=${_str//[-_]/_} | sed -E 's/(^|_)([a-zA-Z])/\u\2/g'` and only first letter was capitalized

Comment: @dingo_d, for which input text you are trying? for `some_string` it is working fine.

Comment: @dingo_d, please check my EDIT in post added output now.

Comment: This works, but only for 2 connected words. So `some_string` works, but `some_other_string` will output `Some_Other_string`. I would have to manually edit for every possible combination...

Comment: @dingo_d, please check my EDIT solution now.

Comment: Works! Thanks! I need to look into `awk` Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

pure **bash**:

```
#!/bin/bash

camel_case(){
    local d display string
    declare -a strings          # = scope local

    [ "$2" ] && d="$2" || d=" " # optional output delimiter
    ifs_ini="$IFS"
    IFS+='_-'                   # we keep initial IFS
    strings=( "$1" )            # array
    for string in ${strings[@]} ; do
        display+="${string^}$d"
    done
    echo "${display%$d}"
    IFS="$ifs_ini"
}

camel_case "some-string_here" "_" 
camel_case "some-string_here some strings here" "+" 
camel_case "some-string_here some strings here"

echo "$BASH_VERSION"

exit
```

**output**:

```
Some_String_Here
Some+String+Here+Some+Strings+Here
Some String Here Some Strings Here
4.4.18(1) release
```

Comment: The question is tagged `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: sorry, but it changed, I follow bash... but bash can be *a* solution, no?

Comment: As is, the code won't work in `zsh`, but could probably be easily adapted.

Comment: I think It's better to restore IFS at the end of the function.

Comment: You can use `local IFS` - that's a simpler alternative.

Comment: normally yes, but to reply on demand and for more readability

Answer (score 2):

This being `zsh`, you don't need `sed` (or even a function, really):

```
$ s=some-string-bar
$ print ${(C)s:gs/-/_}
Some_String_Bar
```

The `(C)` flag capitalizes words (where "words" are defined as sequences of alphanumeric characters separated by other characters); `:gs/-/_` replaces hyphens with underscores.

If you really want a function, it's `cap_case () { print ${(C)1:gs/-/_} }`.

Comment: It's a shame the question was originally tagged [tag:bash] - since it was changed, this is far and away the best answer.

Comment: I agree :), but it's not clear it's actually applicable. The OP hasn't clarified if they are *executing* a script with `zsh`, or just running a `bash` (or possibly POSIX) shell script *from* their login `zsh` instance.

Comment: The other thing to consider is whether the string may contain non-word characters other than `_` and `-` which we don't want to upcase the following character.  It doesn't *seem* likely in context, but the question is insufficiently precise in that respect, too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign to `_capitalize` - you set a `_capitalize` environment variable for the empty command that you piped into `sed`.

You probably meant

```
_capitalize=$(<<<"${_str//[-_]/_}" sed -E 's/(^|_)([a-zA-Z])/\1\u\2/g')
```

Note also that `${//}` isn't standard shell, so you really ought to specify an interpreter other than `sh`.

A simpler approach would be simply:

```
#!/bin/sh

cap_case() {
    printf "Capitalize: "
    echo "$*" | sed -e 'y/-/_/' -e 's/\(^\|_\)[[:alpha:]]/\U&/g'
}

echo $(cap_case "snake_case")
```

Note that the `\u` / `\U` replacement is a GNU extension to sed - if you're using a non-GNU implementation, check whether it supports this feature.

Comment: Tried that, I get usomeustring when I test `some-string`. It seems that sed will replace `_` as well.

Comment: The second snippet you added just lowercases my string. Is it because I'm on mac OS?

Comment: It could be - does your sed support `\u`?  If not, you'll need to make sure you're using the GNU implementation (perhaps called `gsed`?) or use another means to change the case.  If you _are_ using GNU sed, make sure you've not put it into strict mode by setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment.

Comment: It's also possible that your shell understands `\u` and `\U` as Unicode character escapes, even within single-quotes.  POSIX-compliant shells should not do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this gnu sed

```
echo 'some_other-string' | sed -E 's/(^.)/\u&/;s/[_-](.)/_\u\1/g'
```

**Explains :**

```
s/(^.)/\u&/
```

(^.) match the first char and \u& put the match in capital letter.

```
s/[_-](.)/_\u\1/g
```

[_-](.) capture a char preceded by _ or - and replace it by _ and the matched char in capital letter.

The g at the end tell sed to make the replacement for each char which meet the criteria

Comment: @TobySpeight Add explains like you ask.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, i have add gnu sed in the answer and the code from the OP (sed -E 's/(^|_)([a-zA-Z])/\u\2/g')

Comment: So the explanation should be that you use `echo` to print the input to `sed`, and you've changed the sed command to match beginning of line separately from `-` or `_`.   Just describe what the OP needs to do differently.

Comment: my mac will become usome_uother_ustring